# Set up logging for a script or interactive session in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to be able to log from jupyter notebooks into stderr without writing any information about logging in jupyter notebook itself and I want to be able to log into a file when a script starts.

By deafult, in jupyter notebook the logging is set to warning, so I need to modify it to be an info for in code.py.

I have some code in a module:

```
code.py

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
if logger.level == 30:
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.handlers = [handler] + logger.handlers

def do_something_cool():
        logger.info("You are cool")
```

In jupyter notebook it apperas the way I want.

When I use this function from the script, I do following:

```
my_script.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler = logging.FileHandler(str(DIRECTORY / 'log_model_info.log'))
    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

It looks like a hack for me what I do in `code.py`
Is there a better way how to handle it?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev attempted

Comment: For starters, your last code is not even valid Python.

Comment: I've written basic info to get you going in the answer. The specific errors in your code: 1)`StreamHandler` accepts a file-like object, not file name; 2)default level of root logger is `WARN`, so `logger.info` will not be written until you change the level; 3) setting `handlers` explicitly is not supported, use `addHandler()`.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Basic Logging Tutorial — Python 2.7.15 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#basic-logging-tutorial), you set up logging via either [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html?highlight=basicconfig#logging.basicConfig), e.g.:

```
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.INFO)   # stream=sys.stderr is the default,
                                                             # so you can omit it
```

or, to a file:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='log_model_info.log', level=logging.INFO)
```

or by adding handlers, adjusting levels, setting formats etc by hand via other [`logging` API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) -- `logger.addHandler()`, `logger.setLevel()` etc.

---

**For your specific case, `basicConfig()` should be enough:** use `stream` for interactive console (or omit it altogether since `stream=sys.stderr` is the default) and `filename` for script as shown in examples below. In both cases, you need to adjust level to at least INFO because the default for the root logger is WARN.

There's also no need to get a `Logger` object if you will only use the root logger -- use the module-level logging functions.

So, your first code will become:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def do_something_cool():
    logging.info("You are cool")
```

and the second:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='log_model_info.log', level=logging.INFO)
```

---

Here's also my typical logging setup code for unattended scripts -- just so you get an idea what custom `logging` setup code looks like:

```
# set up logging #####################################
import sys,logging,logging.handlers,os.path
#place log alongside the script
log_file=os.path.splitext(__file__)[0]+".log"
l = logging.getLogger()
l.setLevel(logging.INFO)
f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(process)d:%(thread)d %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
h=logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
h.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
h.setFormatter(f)
l.addHandler(h)
h=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file,maxBytes=1024**2,backupCount=1)
h.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
h.setFormatter(f)
l.addHandler(h)
del h,f
#hook to log unhandled exceptions
def excepthook(type,value,traceback):
    logging.error("Unhandled exception occured",exc_info=(type,value,traceback))
    #Don't need another copy of traceback on stderr
    if old_excepthook!=sys.__excepthook__:
        old_excepthook(type,value,traceback)
old_excepthook = sys.excepthook
sys.excepthook = excepthook
del log_file,os
# ####################################################
```

Comment: I edited my question. I figured out what peoblem I have, basically, I am worried about the style and code smell because it doesnt seem to me to be a good colution.

Comment: Bit that would mean, I need to add `logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.INFO)` in each jupyter notebook, which I dont want to do. I want to have it more out-of-the-box, so that by default it will be writen to stderr and only when specified, then into a file.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. You'll have to define your `def do_something_cool():` in every jupyter notebook just as well -- so why not include logging setup code, too? That said, your original `print()` would work just fine for an interactive session, no need to get `logging` involved -- but you specifically asked for `logging`, so I answered about it. Without knowing your specific use case and requirements, I can't say anything more specific, and that would probably be another question, unrelated to how to set up `logging`.

Comment: `do_something_cool()`is not defined in each notebook, it is called in each notebook. It is defined in `code.py`. print will work for an interactive yes, but once a function `do_something_cool()` is called from `script.py`it should be logged into a file. I solved the problem (see above) but I think it is not an elegant solution. This is a problem. I dont want to specify `logging`in each notebook because I want to make it backcompatible and not rerun now all notebooks.

Comment: See the update. I don't see how that code is not elegant and why you cannot place it to `code.py` or whatever just as well.